# How to use VS 2015 MSBuild to build .vdproj

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, vdproj

With VS 2010 or 2013, We can use this command to build .vdproj project(VSI):

```
<Exec Command="&quot;$(ProgramFiles)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.com&quot; your.vdproj /build &quot;Debug|AnyCPU&quot;"/>
```

But in vs 2015, the VSI is an extension of vs. And the similar command(9.0 => 14.0) will get an error.

Anybody know how to solve it?

Comment: MSBuild cannot build .vdproj projects. You should use Visual Studio (devenv.com) for this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved this problem by change the DWORD value for

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0_Config\MSBuild\EnableOutOfProcBuild

registry value to 0.

If this doesn't exist you can create it as a DWORD.

Comment: where are you adding the DWORD value?

Answer (score 11):

[Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Installer Projects](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f1cc3f3e-c300-40a7-8797-c509fb8933b9) extension must be installed.

Comment: I have installed it and the vdproj can be built in VS. And now I want to build it by command line.

Comment: Finally, I use vs 2013 to do the command line compile. Thank you.